# Jittery WebGL Scroller

Tags: webgl

I've built a scroller prototype using WebGL. The problem is, when it's combined with other non-WebGL elements on the same page, the scroller becomes jittery and the quality is quite poor. You can see a demo here (scroller is at the bottom, ignore the Chinese characters) - http://viewer-test.appspot.com/Viewer.html?type=presentation&id=6a169bb8-e440-4338-9e3a-8b5e429f32ee&showui=false Even if I take out the video, the scroller still slows when the CPU spikes every time that RSS feed top right shows a new feed snippet.

I had considered using Web Workers to run the scroller on a different thread, but came across another post in this forum that said that Web Workers can't be used with WebGL. What are my other options to ensure smooth scrolling?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [RequestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) for your animation callbacks? If not, you should. It's managed by the browser to time the draw of your element with the others on the page and with the system screen sync, so you get the smoothest presentation possible. If you do your animation using setTimeout or setInterval, you'll almost always end up out of sync with the pages rendering, which leads to dropped frames and stutters.

Comment: Yes, I am using requestAnimationFrame, or rather, requestAnimFrame and those are the results I'm getting.

Comment: I've tried removing the WebGL and just rendering to a 2D canvas with the same poor performance results - http://viewer-test.appspot.com/Viewer.html?type=presentation&id=d4567f0f-76e6-4b8f-a8f9-ee1c4712f16c&showui=false